# Node.js handle responses from chained promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have 3 functions and each of them return a promise. How can I assign the response from each promise to a defined object?

This is my code:

```
  const runResponse = {
    webAudits: [],
    webJourneys: [],
    appJourneys: []
  };

  webAuditsFailures(req)
  .then(
    appJourneysFailures(req)
  )
  .then(
    webJourneysFailures(req)
  ).then(
    res.status(201).json({ reports: runResponse })
  );
```

This is what I've tried:

```
webAuditsFailures(req)
  .then(
    (response) => {
      runResponse.webAudits = response
    },
    appJourneysFailures(req)
  )
  .then(
    (response) => {
      runResponse.appJourneys = response
    },
    webJourneysFailures(req)
  ).then(
    (response) => {
      runResponse.webJourneys = response
    },
    res.status(201).json({ reports: runResponse })
  );
```

But it doesn't works as expected because the `webAuditsFailures` is called again even if it didn't end and I don't understand why...

These are other failed attempts to fix this:

Using `await`

```
  const webAudits = await webAuditsFailures(req);
  const appJourneys = await appJourneysFailures(req);
  const webJourneys = await webJourneysFailures(req);

  runResponse.webAudits = webAudits;
  runResponse.webJourneys = webJourneys;
  runResponse.appJourneys = appJourneys;
```

The same thing happens with this:

```
 const webAudits = await webAuditsFailures(req);
 runResponse.webAudits = webAudits;
```

Using the `co` module:

```
  co(function* () {
    var runResponse = yield {
      webAudits: webAuditsFailures(req),
      webJourneys: appJourneysFailures(req),
      appJourneys: webJourneysFailures(req)
    };
    res.status(201).json({ reports: runResponse });
  });
```

Using `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([webAuditsFailures(req), appJourneysFailures(req),
  webJourneysFailures(req)])
    .then(function(allData) {
      res.status(201).json({ reports: allData });
  });
```

This is the `webAuditsFailures` function, which sequentially calls another functions that return a promise

```
export default async (req) => {
  const report = req.body.webAudits;
  const def = deferred();

  if(report.length > 0) {
    var reportList = [];
    for(const [reportIndex, item] of report.entries()) {
      for(const [runIndex, run] of item.runs.entries()) {
        const result = await waComplianceBusiness(req, run.id);
        var failureList = [];
        if(result.data.overviews) {
          const compliance = result.data.overviews[0].compliance;
          if(compliance) {
            for(const [index, rule] of compliance.entries()) {
              const response = await waRuleOverview(req, run.id, rule.id);
              const failedConditions = response.data.failedConditions;
              const ruleName = response.data.ruleName;

              if(response.data.pagesFailed > 0) {
                for(const [condIndex, condition] of failedConditions.entries()) {
                  const request = {
                    itemId: condition.conditionResult.id,
                    itemType: condition.conditionResult.idType,
                    parentId: condition.conditionResult.parentId,
                    parentType: condition.conditionResult.parentType
                  }
                  const body = {
                    runId: run.id,
                    ruleId: rule.id,
                    payload: request
                  }

                  waConditionOverview(req, body).done(response => {
                    // do stuff here
                  });
                }
              }
            }
            if(failureList.length > 0) {
              item.runs[runIndex].failures = failureList;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    def.resolve(report);
    return def.promise
  }
  else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the webAuditsFailures() function and explain what is req?

Comment: @MarioSantini I updated the question. Req is the route request

Comment: What is `deferred()`, why not use `new Promise()`? Also you are returning an `[]` or `def.promise` which might make the calling code confused. You probably want to stick with one return type.

Comment: @styfle Deferred is a node module https://www.npmjs.com/package/deferred ... I don't use `new Promise()` because I don't know how to implement it in my code

Comment: Maybe I got it. Your function is marked as *async*, this return a promise when you call the function. The implication is that your code continue to run and not wait if you don't use *await*. As it is expecting you to handle the promise, as you do implementing the *.then()* part.

Comment: @MarioSantini I think you're right. But how can I fix this?

Comment: If your code have to be synchronous you shoud use *await* instead of put the code in the *.then()* functions. So you flow are going to stop until the promise returned is resolved or rejected. And please consider to use the return statement in the function you use to resolve promises as @PeterMader propose.

Comment: I tried to use await but it still re-calls the `webAuditsFailures` function ... this is the code: 
`const webAudits = await webAuditsFailures(req);  `
`const appJourneys = await appJourneysFailures(req);  `
`const webJourneys = await webJourneysFailures(req);`

Comment: @MarioSantini I updated my question with my other attempts to solve this

Comment: Sorry could not follow, the issue is that the function is called twice or you don't have the values you want back.

Comment: Using `.then()` I'm not able to receive the values and using the other methods described in the question I get the issue that the function is called again even if its execution didn't finish yet

Comment: @Valip It could be the line: *waConditionOverview(req, body).done* you should use await here, otherwise you will have the promise running and the function not blocked.

Comment: I commented that part of code and it does the same

Comment: @Valip I suggest you to try to write a minimal working example, and then add one thing at the time and then you'll figured out what breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
waConditionOverview(req, body).done(response => {
  // do stuff here
});
```

You're performing an async action but not waiting for the result. Don't use the deferred model - use `util.promisify` for callbacks.

In addition, I warmly recommend not mutating the request/resposne like this but storing the information in objects and returning those.

Here is how you'd write the code:

```
export default async (req) => {
  const report = req.body.webAudits;  
  if(report.length === 0) return;
  const runs = Array.from(report.entries(), ([i, item]) => item.runs.entries());
  for (const [_, run] of runs) {
    const result = await waComplianceBusiness(req, run.id);
    var failureList = [];
    if (!result.data.overviews) {
      continue;
    }
    const compliance = result.data.overviews[0].compliance;
    if(!compliance) {
      continue;
    }
    for(const [_, rule] of compliance.entries()) {
      const response = await waRuleOverview(req, run.id, rule.id);
      const { failedConditions, ruleName} = response.data;

      if(failureList.length > 0) {
        item.runs[runIndex].failures = failureList;
      }
      if(response.data.pagesFailed === 0) continue;

      for(const [_, condition] of failedConditions.entries()) {
        const request = {
          itemId: condition.conditionResult.id,
          itemType: condition.conditionResult.idType,
          parentId: condition.conditionResult.parentId,
          parentType: condition.conditionResult.parentType
        }
        const body = { runId: run.id, ruleId: rule.id, payload: request}
        const reponse = await waConditionOverview(req, body);
        // do stuff here
        // update response
        // update report, so next time we try it's updated and doesn't return empty;
      }
    }
  }
  return report;
}
```

Comment: This works perfect, but if I try to call all of my 3 functions using await  ( `const webAudits = await webAuditsFailures(req);
  const appJourneys = await appJourneysFailures(req);
  const webJourneys = await webJourneysFailures(req);` ) then it will re-call the first function (webAuditsFailures) right after it returns a response and doesn't wait for the other 2 functions to finish ... why it does this?

Comment: Basically it does this: call `webAuditsFailures`, return response for it, call `appJourneysFailures`, call `webAuditsFailures`, return response for `appJourneysFailures` (`webAuditsFailures` is still running), call `webJourneysFailures`, return response for it, return response again for `webAuditsFailures` then it calls again the `appJourneysFailures` and `webJourneysFailures` functions ... hopefully this gives you a better understanding of the issue

Comment: I found that the problem is not the `webAuditsFailures` function because the route is re-called every time exactly after 2 minutes (if the post request takes less than 2 minutes then there is no problem). I posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876257/express-post-request-gives-err-empty-response-after-4-mins

Answer (score 1):

In a promise chain, the current `.then()` should return a promise. The result of this promise will be passed to the next `.then()`:

```
webAuditsFailures(req)
  .then((response) => {
    runResponse.webAudits = response;
    return appJourneysFailures(req); // return a promise
  })
  .then((response) => { // response contains the result of the promise
    runResponse.appJourneys = response;
    return webJourneysFailures(req);
  })
  .then((response) => {
    runResponse.webJourneys = response;
    res.status(201).json({ reports: runResponse });
  });
```

Depending on what `.json()` in the last `.then()` does, you should return that as well if there are other `.then()`s in the promise chain.

Comment: Using this approach leads to the same problem...the function `webAuditsFailures` is getting called again even if it didn't return anything