# Express post request gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http-post

I'm building a node.js and express.js web app and it doesn't works as expected when a post request takes longer than 2 mins.
What happens is that after 2 mins my `express` route is re-called and then, after another 2 mins (4 mins in total) I get this error in the network tab for that post request:

> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I read that `express` has a default timeout set to 2 mins, but that applies only to get requests...

This is my route:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', authenticate, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('here');
  setTimeout(function() {
    res.status(201).json({success: true});   
  }, 400000);
})
```

It prints `here` to the console when I make the post request, and then it prints again `here` after 2 minutes.

This is my `index` file from server:

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
  hot: true,
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  noInfo: true
}));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running on localhost:3000'));
app.timeout = 700000;
```

There are already 2 weeks since I'm facing this issue and any ideas or solutions would help me a lot. Please let me know if I need to provide more details.

Comment: Add a `.catch(err => console.log(err))` into your `webAuditsFailures` call. It could help to see some errors.

Comment: Like this? `response.catch(err => console.log(err));`

Comment: `webAuditsFailures(req).then((response) => { ... }).catch((err) => console.log(err));`

Comment: There are no errors showing up in the console

Comment: So I would put some `console.log(...)` all the way in `webAuditsFailures` in order to know where your request is stuck. Probably inside one of `waComplianceBusiness` / `waRuleOverview` / `waConditionOverview`

Comment: It fails even if I remove the loop that contains the call to the `waConditionOverview` function

Comment: Testing with chunks of the same data works perfect if the request takes less than 2 mins

Comment: So the problem is not from `webAuditsFailures` codes. What `express` configuration do you use? all default?

Comment: Just the one from my `index.js` file added to the question body

Comment: The strange thing is that I get `Empty reply from server` using curl, and this happens exactly after 2 minutes

Comment: I guess after 2 minute the timeout trigger, then express send an empty response. You could maybe catch the timeout event from express and send a manual response, so it's not empty. 

And idk but what happen when your treatment `webAuditsFailures` finally end (imagine the treatment takes 3 min), does something get sent?

Comment: I never get a response from the post route, only the failure message that appears at 4.0 mins. Can you please tell me how can I catch the timeout event from express?

Comment: Maybe this is your client (who do the request) that timeout and it's own timeout is 4 min. Idk about getting the event, you gotta google it.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT can you please check my updated question? I found out that simply adding a setTimeout function will cause the same problem

Comment: What is `authenticate`? can you remove it and see what happen

Comment: Removed both `authenticate` and `async` but still having the same problem..

Comment: Look at [how handle errors in express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), display them out

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by removing the web browser's timeout as explained here:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2174