# Fetch API in react component on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm having an issue calling a service from my website on Form component submit. Any help would be appreciated.

Website running on localhost:3000
Service running on localhost:4041

Service never gets when requesting from website. It's working with postman though.

Error message in console after 30s

**Form.jsx:115 POST http://localhost:4041/check_convention net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

Any ideas why?

**UPDATE**

I'm seeing something quite interesting. On submit it does not hit the server. When I open Firefox, open the console, see the check_convention request, attempt to Edit and Resent the request. I populate body and send, it then passes and shows:

'{"ok":true,"error":"Unable to validate given currencies"}'

Which tells me it is now working. But only when I Edit and Resend. Why?

**cURL**

```js
curl "http://localhost:4041/check_convention" ^
  -H "Referer: http://localhost:3000/execution" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
  --data-binary "^{^\^"ccy1^\^":^\^"USD^\^",^\^"ccy2^\^":^\^"GBP^\^"^}" ^
  --compressed

curl "http://localhost:4041/check_convention" ^
  -X "OPTIONS" ^
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" ^
  -H "Accept: */*" ^
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" ^
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type" ^
  -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty" ^
  -H "Referer: http://localhost:3000/execution" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7" ^
  --compressed
```

**Form Component**

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {}
  }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        this.postToCurrencyService()
        event.preventDefault()
    }
    
    postToCurrencyService = () => {
        const body = {ccy1: 'GBP', ccy2: 'USD'}
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        };
        // when inspecting I see it gets to fetch then continues and renders and does not hit .then
        fetch('http://localhost:4041/check_convention', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data ))
    }
  
   render () {
      <div></div>
   }



}
```

**App**

```js
const server = require("./server.js")

const port = process.env.PORT || 4041;

server.use((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
})

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

**Server**

```js
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/check_convention', (req, res) => {
    const { ccy1, ccy2 } = req.body
    let conventionChecker = new ConventionValidator(currencyList, currencyPriorityList)
    if (conventionChecker.isValid(ccy1, ccy2)) {
        const result = conventionChecker.asConvention(ccy1, ccy2);
        return res.json({ok: true, result})
    }
    return res.json({ok: true, error: 'Unable to validate given currencies'})
})
```

Comment: Maybe this is the issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876257/express-post-request-gives-err-empty-response

Comment: Have you verified `app.post...` is receiving the POST request? Is anything throwing an error in the server?

Comment: The request should not take so long... The problem is that it isn't reaching the service when I fetch.  Eventually times out

Comment: @DrewReese It is not. No errors thrown on the server

Comment: Working in postman. Can you check and share the request from your network tab. Copy as curl.

Comment: When adding next() to the end of my server.use(... I get - Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4041/check_convention' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. - If I don't add next, in the network tab, I get

Comment: I updated the post with cURL above

Answer (score 0):

Solution - put in Server before app.post(....) not in App.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next()
})
```